# What solution does Maple give to this difference equation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, special-functions, maple, hypergeometric-function

Here is a set of difference equations for y[n]

62022240 + 545995032 n + 2056791388 n^2 + 4333244560 n^3 + 
  5587600700 n^4 + 4517982000 n^5 + 2238010000 n^6 + 621200000 n^7 + 
  74000000 n^8 + (-19027008 - 158454120 n - 566231672 n^2 - 
     1135130960 n^3 - 1397526400 n^4 - 1082880000 n^5 - 
     516080000 n^6 - 138400000 n^7 - 16000000 n^8) y[n] + 
  3 (2 + 5 n) (3 + 5 n)^2 (4 + 5 n) (6 + 5 n) (5 + 6 n) (7 + 
     6 n) (31 + 20 n) y[1 + n] == 0, y[1] == 158/31

or equivalently

4 (3 + 2 n) (5168520 + 
     n (42053906 + 
        5 n (28672669 + 
           5 n (10621126 + 
              5 n (2308917 + 
                 10 n (147271 + 20 n (2551 + 370 n))))))) + (-8 (1 + 
       n) (3 + 2 n) (8 + 5 n) (7 + 10 n) (9 + 10 n) (11 + 10 n) (13 + 
       10 n) (11 + 20 n)) y[n] + 
  3 (2 + 5 n) (3 + 5 n)^2 (4 + 5 n) (6 + 5 n) (5 + 6 n) (7 + 
     6 n) (31 + 20 n) y[1 + n] == 0, y[1] == 158/31

I would appreciate it if a reader could provide the Maple solution to these equations--as I have been analyzing it with Mathematica, and obtaining a "hypergeometric-rich" solution of large complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Maple doesn't return any hypergeometrics. Its solution has a lot of Gamma functions and a finite summation:

```
-(3+5*n)*Pi^(1/2)*GAMMA(n+13/10)*GAMMA(n+11/10)*GAMMA(n+9/10)*GAMMA(n+7/10)*GAMMA(n+3/2)*(-cos((1/5)*Pi)+2*cos((1/5)*Pi)^2-1)*64^n*27^(-n)*GAMMA(1+n)*(Sum((4/3)*(cos((1/5)*Pi)+1)*(2*cos((1/5)*Pi)-1)*GAMMA(n1+7/5)*GAMMA(n1+9/5)*GAMMA(n1+11/6)*GAMMA(n1+11/5)*GAMMA(n1+13/6)*GAMMA(n1+8/5)*(2*n1+3)*(9250000*n1^7+63775000*n1^6+184088750*n1^5+288614625*n1^4+265528150*n1^3+143363345*n1^2+42053906*n1+5168520)/(GAMMA(2+n1)*27^(-n1-1)*64^(n1+1)*(2*cos((1/5)*Pi)+1)*(cos((1/5)*Pi)-1)*GAMMA(n1+5/2)*GAMMA(n1+17/10)*GAMMA(n1+19/10)*GAMMA(n1+21/10)*GAMMA(n1+23/10)*Pi^(1/2)*(8+5*n1)*(6*n1+5)*(5*n1+2)*(5*n1+4)*(5*n1+6)*(6*n1+7)*(5*n1+3)^2), n1 = 1 .. n-1)+7900/1287)/((20*n+11)*GAMMA(n+3/5)*GAMMA(n+7/6)*GAMMA(n+6/5)*GAMMA(n+5/6)*GAMMA(n+4/5)*GAMMA(n+2/5)*(cos((1/5)*Pi)+2*cos((1/5)*Pi)^2-1))
```

Comment: Thanks very, very much Carl Love! I find that very interesting. Might I ask you to send me a copy of the output at slater@kitp.ucsb.edu? (And/or is it inappropriate/unsuitable to post the output itself on the stack exchange?)

Comment: This equation pertains to issues in quantum-information and random matrix theory (http://arxiv.org/find/quant-ph/1/au:+Slater_P/0/1/0/all/0/1). It is the first (k=1) in a series of increasingly larger systems (for which I presently also have k=2,3). I strongly suspect that this Maple output simplifies greatly, in particular if it is multiplied by a factor (which I tried to post in LaTeX form--but led to too many characters in the comment).

Comment: I emailed you a PDF transcript of the Maple session. I don't know what you mean by "post the output itself." Doesn't my Answer above contain "the output itself"? Please give my Answer a Vote Up.

Comment: OK, thanks again (got the email)! I hadn't (stupidly) seen how to observe and grab the complete output using the black bar. I pasted this into a Maple (14) worksheet and will try to simplify it there, and will try it on my other (presently) two (increasingly large) difference equations. I will also try to input it to Mathematica (my more "native" language). But maybe it's not entirely clear at this point that the summation in the formula will not also yield hypergeometric results (as I obtained in Mathematica). Because of length limits, I have an immediately next (website) comment too.

Comment: This difference equation has also been the subject of an earlier (Mathematica) stack exchange item: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/find-rsolve-solution-reflecting-special-structure-of-differencerootfunction/124428#124428

Comment: I tried to give Carl Love's answer a (deserved) "Vote Up" (by clicking on "votes") but not too sure I succeeded. (I'm something of a novice in such matters.) If this didn't work how should I do it?

Comment: I did translate the Maple output of Love to Mathematica and performed the (implicit) summation. The result has a very similar nature to the one originally obtained in Mathematica, with the same set of hypergeometric terms, all with argument 27/64, appearing. So, it would seem that the two languages take similar approaches (as to which I was curious) to the recurrence equations.

Comment: As indicated, I copied the Maple output to Mathematica, and performed the computation--but first I seemed to have to considerably simplify the summand. I'd still like to seem how Maple itself completes the computation (that is carries out the summation). What command is needed (so I could possibly try)? Mathematica seems to immediately carry out the summation when it sees it, and Maple to hold it in abeyance.

Comment: The command is **value**, but in this case it is unable to do the symbolic summation. To give a "Vote Up", click on the up arrow above the number in the upper left corner of the Answer.

Comment: Thanks! I did give the vote up. Is Maple unable to do the symbolic summation, in the sense that it is too computationally challenging (too much time required). This seemed also to be the case, initially when I placed the Maple output into Mathematica. However, I applied FullSimplify to the summand, got substantial simplification, and then the summation was performed rather readily.

Comment: Maple doesn't usually put any time limit on operations, although it's possible to include time limits programmatically if you want to. I forgot to tell Maple to assume that the upper limit of summation is a nonnegative integer. It seems odd that one would have to do this. The command is **value(Y) assuming n::posint**, where **Y** is the output of the **rsolve** command. Issuing this command, it is taking a long time. So far, it's taken about two hours CPU time, distributed over eight threads.

Comment: I needed to kill the summation after three hours because I needed to shut down the computer for an unrelated reason.

Comment: Thanks, of course, for all your efforts, C. Love! Much appreciated! Did you simplify the summand before trying to execute the summation (which seemed to be important in the Mathematica counterpart for the execution to terminate)?

Comment: I hadn't simplified first. So now I tried that. The simplification alters the expression, although it's not immediately obvious that it's any simpler. Alas, this didn't seem to help with the summation.